# How can I add an application to the system to execute it via ALT+F2?

Tags: 12.10

I would like to know how I register an application in Ubuntu 12.10 in a way that I can access it via ALT+F2+"Name of the application"?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles

Comment: Any application that is installed can be accessed by ALT+F2.  In your case you have downloaded a zip file which will need to be extracted, possibly compiled and installed.  Edit the question to tell us what you have downloaded and from where so we can advise further

Answer (score 0):

Any application that you install, you can access via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.  As an example I have installed Gimp, and then pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, typed Gimp, and this is what I get.

[image]

I click on Gimp to run it, and it runs OK.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not what I meant. I know that any software that I install automatically can be accessed via ALT+F2 but in this case I would like to access an application that I downloaded as a .zip file.

Comment: @Skadier do you not believe that is an important part of the question (and as such should be included in the question)?